# Docker-compose doesn't copy Test files from local folder into Container , but copies everything else

Tags: javascript, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

Consider the docker-compose :

```
 employee_app:
    container_name: EmployeeContainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9999:3000"
    depends_on:
      - elastic
      
      
  ... more services
```

And the Dockerfile of `employee` app :

```
FROM node:14

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/

RUN npm i 
ENTRYPOINT npm start


....
```

I have a lot of folders in the `employee` app and when I `docker-compose up` it copies everything , except for the `.test.js` files.

Why ?

Comment: Do you have a .dockerignore file or anything like that?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V: Yes , you're a genius!

Comment: glad I could help, haha! :)

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V: Post as an answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, I thought I'd be more formal & a more complete answer. When using Docker, if you want something included inside the container you need to make sure that you don't have a `.dockerignore` file, in hindsight it's obvious, like any other ignore file, you're choosing to exclude things from whatever it is you're working on. I.E. `.gitignore`, same idea, different tool I guess?

*Though*, as you mentioned `*.test.js`, I'd wonder why you'd want that in your container & not as a part of your CI process, even if you run your tests *via* Docker, i.e. if you look at [this example](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/#production), it could save you removing anything from your `.dockerignore` file. But of course this is a context specific subject & it's entirely up to you & your team at the end of the day, it's nothing more than a suggestion at most.

Hope that helps!